# Confused about Turing Recognizability

Tags: turing-machines, chomsky-hierarchy

If Turing Recognizability means a T.M. will either halt on input $w$ if $w$ is in the language, or run forever if $w$ is not in the language.

How can we know the language is Turing Recognizable if we run the T.M. on a $w$ not in the language and thus it never halts so we do not get to the next input.

Comment: You can run a Turing machine for k steps

Answer (score 1):

> How can we know the language is Turing Recognizable if we run the T.M. on a w not in the language and thus it never halts so we do not get to the next input.

We don't determine that a language is Turing recognizable by *running* it; rather, we determine that it is recognizable through a mathematical argument. We prove this by giving a machine $M$, and *proving* that for all inputs $w$, the machine $M$ will accept if $w$ is in the language and either halt or run forever otherwise.

The reason we do this by proof is that we can't run it for all possible inputs (that would be impossible and take an infinite amount of time). So instead, we use a mathematical proof that works for *all* possible inputs at once.

Answer (score 0):

A language $L$ is recognisable if there exists a TM $M$ s.t $M$ accepts $w$ if and only if $w \in L$.

Note that the requirement does not necessarily mean $M$ **rejects** $w$; it could simply not halt.

> How can we know the language is Turing Recognizable if we run the T.M. on a w not in the language

Thus to answer your question, I would stipulate that there exists no requirement for $M$ to halt on $w \notin L$

If you simply want to find strings in the language, follow Pal's comment:

For $i=0 \dots n$ steps:

1. Run $M$ on all words up to length $i$ for at most $i$ steps
2. If $M$ accepts, $w$ is in $L(M)$

And by setting $n$ to infinity every $w$ in $L(M)$ will be found.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the confusion is that recognizability is defined in terms of a "there exists" statement.

Recognizability is "one-sided" in regards to "yes" instances and "no" instances. Decidability is a strictly stronger condition than recognizability. Suppose the language $L$ is turing-recognizable (Chomsky Type 0):

There exists a Turing machine $M$ such that:

- If $w$ is in the language $L$, then it is guaranteed $M$ will halt, and yield a "yes" output.
- If $w$ is not in the language $L$, then we know $M$ will not output a "yes", but it does not tell if $M$ will output a "no" or will run forever.

If $L$ is undecidable, then every such $M$ which satisfies the above two conditions also will run forever on certain words $w$ not in $L$. We can also construct a $M$ which halts if and only if $w$ is in $L$ by forcing a loop sequence if a "no" answer is reached.